# Issue with AIR - Facebook Mobile SDK

Tags: facebook, air

Steps to reproduce:

1. Use source for GraphAPI_Mobile_1_8.swc today
2. Add it to a Adobe CS5.5; FLA project
3. Configured and Android 3.0 profile
4. After init - Call:

   ```
   FacebookMobile.login(handleLogin,stage,[],webView)
   ```
5. After facebook login and a few 302 redirects - this ends up being redirected (I can see this in - MobileLoginWindows.as - handleLocationChange to (I replaced the APPID)

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=APPID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&display=touch&type=user_agent&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&m_sess=A9SpI-6Ld3Qvbz

This results in an error being returned from facebook:

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 2 at column 224: EntityRef: expecting ';'

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error (nothing else)

If I use the same URL in a browser (e.g. Firefox) it returns "success" so I can only assume that some http header setting (e.g. UserAgent?) is not set correctly - but I have no idea where to go from here.

Any help suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded version 1.8.1. of the API and there it works just fine.